# How can I use Service Communciation in net 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, .net-5

I used WCF to communciate with my service. I upgraded my project from .net framework to net 5.0. But I found that there's no 'ServiceHost' class. Based on my searching results, net 5.0 doesn't support WCF. Is there a way to communciate with my service?

Comment: Only WCF client is supported in .NET 5. The server-side is not supported. For new developments, gRPC is recommended as an alternative. For existing development, you can either remain on .NET Framework (which will remain supported) or you can look into community initiatives (like Core WCF although that is not production ready).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original implementation of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) was only supported on Windows. However, there is a client port available from the .NET Foundation. It is entirely open source, cross platform, and supported by Microsoft. The core NuGet packages are listed below:

1. System.ServiceModel.Duplex.
2. System.ServiceModel.Federation.
3. System.ServiceModel.Http.
4. System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.
5. System.ServiceModel.Primitives.
6. System.ServiceModel.Security.

The community maintains the server components that complement the aforementioned client libraries. The GitHub repository can be found at [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF). The server components are not officially supported by Microsoft. For an alternative to WCF, consider [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).